# Disable Hash Result?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-ise

Im sure this might be a really simple answer that eludes me, but Ive been playing with this coding for a decent bit now, and need to format it in a more user friendly method.

Here is the code:

```
$OU1 = 'CN=MbrshpOU, OU=Group, DC=place,DC=com'

Write-Host "Select user:"

$UName=Get-ADGroupMember -identity "$OU1" | Select sAMAccountName | Out-GridView -PassThru
$UserName = $UName 

--Using this displays nothing in the Write-Host below: $UserName = ($UName).sAMAccountName

Write-Host ""
Write-Host " The user is: " -NoNewline;
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green $UserName -NoNewline;
Write-Host " is this correct? Y/N " -NoNewline

(Choice code follows)
```

This is what currently happens:

> "The user is: @{sAMAccountName=first.last} is this correct? Y/N >"

What I need is:

> "The user is: first.last is this correct? Y/N >"

Ideas?

Comment: With `-PassThru` you could select multiple `SamAccountName`s, to strip off also the property name I suggest to use `$UserName = $UName[0].SamAccountName` for only the first entry.

Comment: @LotPings Adding that [0] resolved the issue brotha, I appreciate it.If you want to change your comment to an answer, Ill mark it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$OU1 = 'CN=Disabled Users,OU=SecurityGroups,OU=Groups,OU=Production,DC=ad,DC=evotec,DC=xyz'

Write-Host "Select user:"

$UName = Get-ADGroupMember -identity "$OU1" | Get-ADUser -Properties GivenName, SurName | Out-GridView -PassThru
$UserName = $UName

Write-Host ""
Write-Host " The user is: " -NoNewline;
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green ("$($UserName.GivenName) $($UserName.SurName)") -NoNewline;
Write-Host " is this correct? Y/N " -NoNewline
```

My version using Write-Color (my PowerShell module):

```
$OU1 = 'CN=Disabled Users,OU=SecurityGroups,OU=Groups,OU=Production,DC=ad,DC=evotec,DC=xyz'

Write-Host "Select user:"

$UName = Get-ADGroupMember -identity "$OU1" | Get-ADUser -Properties GivenName, SurName | Out-GridView -PassThru
$UserName = $UName

Write-Color -LinesBefore 1 -Text "The user is: ", "$($UserName.GivenName) $($UserName.SurName)", ". Is this correct? Y/N" -Color White, Green, White
```

What you need to know is that `Get-ADGroupMember` has a limited set of properties. That means you need to use `Get-ADuser` to get missing properties that you need.

I would suggest using Write-Color for display, as it's much easier for playing with that kind of scenarios you are using. Here's the link: https://github.com/EvotecIT/PSWriteColor

Of course, I'm assuming you want First and Last Name. If you just want SamAccountName it's much easier.

```
$OU1 = 'CN=Disabled Users,OU=SecurityGroups,OU=Groups,OU=Production,DC=ad,DC=evotec,DC=xyz'

Write-Host "Select user:"

$UName = Get-ADGroupMember -identity "$OU1" | Out-GridView -PassThru
$UserName = $UName

Write-Color -LinesBefore 1 -Text "The user is: ", $UserName.SamAccountName, ". Is this correct? Y/N" -Color White, Green, White
```

Or in case of your code:

```
$OU1 = 'CN=Disabled Users,OU=SecurityGroups,OU=Groups,OU=Production,DC=ad,DC=evotec,DC=xyz'

Write-Host "Select user:"

$UName = Get-ADGroupMember -identity "$OU1" | Get-ADUser -Properties GivenName, SurName | Out-GridView -PassThru
$UserName = $UName

Write-Host ""
Write-Host " The user is: " -NoNewline;
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green $UserName.SamAccountName -NoNewline;
Write-Host " is this correct? Y/N " -NoNewline
```

Comment: Thanks! Wow, a lot of work was put into this answer, very insightful and easy to read - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I see you got you answer, but here is another way to try this...

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $(Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter '*' | 
Select-Object -Property Name, DistinguishedName | 
Out-GridView -PassThru -Title 'Select a Organizational Unit to see the users in that OU').Name | 
Select-Object -Property Name, SamAccountName | 
Out-GridView -PassThru -Title 'Select a username to review' 
Read-Host -Prompt 'The user is displays as: first.last. Is this correct? Y/N >'
```

… all OGV driven, no Write-* needed.

Comment: I love this, Write-Host has always been an oddball thing to work with, Ill be making another program thatll use something similar to what I have listed above, but instead, Ill try your method going forward. I appreciate you taking the time to show me this!

Comment: No worries. Glad it will be useful. Write-Host as a rule should just be avoided, unless you are writing color text to the screen to some other custom reason. Output to the screen is the default for any results, simple string, or variable, unless you set it not to be. Using OGV (https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/b3q0qo/id_like_to_create_a_simple_active_directory_query and https://mcpmag.com/articles/2016/02/17/creating-a-gui-using-out-gridview.aspx) and Show -Command (https://powershell.getchell.org/2018/02/13/poor-mans-gui) to build GUI is quick, though not elegant. But WPF is cool.